# Calculator package and Math Times Pro 2

Tags: errors, calculations, syntax

When I try to use the `calculator` the `mtpro2` package at the same time I get an error message. Recently I found out that this issue has something to do with the `\SQRT` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{calculator}
\begin{document}
    $ \SQRT{x} $
\end{document}
```

I get these messages :

> Missing number, treated as zero. $ \SQRT{x} $ 
>   Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). $ \SQRT{x} $ 
>   Missing = inserted for \ifdim. $ \SQRT{x} $ 
>   Missing control sequence inserted. $ \SQRT{x} $ –

How can I use both packages?

Comment: Any error message in particular or just random complaints about your failure to order adequate quantities of pizza?

Comment: I get these messages :
Missing number, treated as zero. $ \SQRT{x} $
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). $ \SQRT{x} $
Missing = inserted for \ifdim. $ \SQRT{x} $
Missing control sequence inserted. $ \SQRT{x} $

Comment: You could load the `calculator` package first, save its version of `\SRQT` via an instruction such as `\let\CSQRT\SQRT`, and then load the `mtpro2` package. In the body of the document, you'd use `\SQRT` if you want the `mtpro2` version of the macro and `\CSQRT` if you want the `calculator` version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [Manuel's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256410/calculator-package-and-math-times-pro-2/256411?noredirect=1#comment613981_256411), `mtpro2` apparently also defines `\SQRT`. Then `calculator` overwrites that definition since it is loaded later. Hence, when you try to use `\SQRT`, it is `calculator`'s definition which is active. So, the error you get is the same as that with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\begin{document}
    $ \SQRT{x} $
\end{document}
```

This is because the `calculator` tries to take the square root of `x` but `x` is not a number, so it cannot take its square root.

Just in case anybody wants a demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\begin{document}
    \[ \sqrt{x} \]
    \SQRT{9}{\sol}
    \[ \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{9} = \sol \]
    \[ \SQRT{4}{\sol}\sqrt{4} = \sol \]
\end{document}
```

[image: calculations]

To resolve the conflict, you can rename the definition from one or other package (whichever you load first). Because I can test this, I've renamed the command from `calculator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\let\calcSQRT\SQRT
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
    \[ \sqrt{x} \]
    \calcSQRT{9}{\sol}
    \[ \sqrt{x} = \sqrt{9} = \sol \]
    \[ \calcSQRT{4}{\sol}\sqrt{4} = \sol \]
   \[ \SQRT{x} \]
    \calcSQRT{9}{\sol}
    \[ \SQRT{x} = \SQRT{9} = \sol \]
    \[ \calcSQRT{4}{\sol}\SQRT{4} = \sol \]
\end{document}
```

With the relevant lines commented out, the code produces output identical to that shown in the image above.

As posted, [mac has confirmed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256410/calculator-package-and-math-times-pro-2/256411?noredirect=1#comment614099_256411) that the code allows you to continue using `\SQRT` from Math Time Pro 2, although I'm not able to test this myself.

Comment: The problem is that `\SQRT` is also a command from `mtpro2` that outputs quite large slanted roots. The question is basically how to get the two commands (of course, different names are needed, may be `\calcSQRT` for the `calculator` and `\SQRT` for the `mtpro2` one).

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. Sigh. I guess it doesn't do any checking, then?

Comment: I agree. The `\SQRT` command exists in both packages. For small formulas i can use the `\sqrt` command. But what if I have to type something like `\[ \SQRT{\frac{\frac{12345}{1234}}{\frac{12345}{123}}}  \]` if I want to use the mtpro2 root symbol? Can a command wih a new name be created?

Comment: @mac Can you try the code above with the commented lines uncommented? They can't work for me as I don't have the font package. The commented version works i.e. `\calcSQRT` works fine. But I don't know how `mtpro2` defines `\SQRT` so a different approach may be needed if this one doesn't fly. (This assumes the easiest case.)

Comment: @Manuel Do you want me to delete this so you can answer? I mean, obviously you can answer anyway, but you know what I mean.

Comment: @cfr I compiled the code above with the commented lines uncommented and I get exactly what I want. Your solution is correct. I must load the `calculator` package before `mtpro2` and rename the `\SQRT` command.

Comment: @cfr No problem at all, edit the remaining lines as `@mac said and everything is all right.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks. I've edited the question now I've been assured it works!